# Fourier Series (finite case)

Tags: definite-integrals, fourier-series, maxima-minima

Suppose we have a function $f \in C([-\pi,\pi])$ and another function $g(t)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k \sin (kt)$. Determine the numbers $a_1, a_2,..., a_n$ for which the integral $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(f(t)-g(t))^2dt$ is minimal.

Comment: It is the usual orthogonal projection procedure that you use in finding the Fourier series of a $L^2$ function.

Comment: @Ian Not exactly usual, as you only take the $a_k$ : you just take the odd part of the Fourier series, but it is stil an orthogonal projection

Comment: @Thomas Right, but it is still how you find the coefficients of the sines in the Fourier series.

Comment: Well clearly if $g$ is a Fourier series of $f$, the difference $f(t)-g(t)$ will be minimal...

Comment: How do you compute the coordinate of the orthogonal projection of a vector on a subspace once you know an orthogonal base of this subspace ? Here the subspace is the space generated by the $\sin (kt)$, and the orthogonal vector are these vectors (the finctions $\sin(kt)$.